# BigInteger class in Java?

Tags: java

I do not understand about the BigInteger class in Java. Can you help me,,,
public

public BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)

bitLength parameter was his explanation of how?

thanks you

Answer (score 4):

This [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Random%29) creates a random `BigInteger` of the specified length.